# Are NFT policies interchangeable between networks?

Tags: nft, native-assets, minting, policy, mintingpolicy

Generating a policy doesn't require a running node; the `cardano-cli` alone is sufficient. Since no connection is made to the network, can I assume there's no difference between a policy on preprod and mainnet? In other words, can I use the same policy to mint on all the different networks?

The only difference will be the expiry slot because the reference slot will differ between networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, they are. I've minted NFTs on preprod and mainnet with the exact same keys and policy.

Here's the policy on preprod:
https://preprod.venster.io/policies/3333acb55ed79731ea6658abb74f453cbb87e15aee01a7aab484b2a6

Here's the same policy on mainnet:
https://venster.io/policies/3333acb55ed79731ea6658abb74f453cbb87e15aee01a7aab484b2a6